# Uncaught (in promise) Error: Unknown layer: KerasLayer

Tags: javascript, python, tensorflow, tensorflow.js, tensorflowjs-converter

I'm trying to load a model using tf.loadLayersModel('path'); from Tensorflow js and I have too many problems loading the model.

I've trained my model in python. And converted the format from keras to tfjs_layers_model using:

```
!pip install tensorflowjs
!tensorflowjs_converter --input_format=keras --output_format=tfjs_layers_model model/my_model.h5 model
```

This way I can convert my model from h5 to JSON, so I can load it in javascript.

The problem is that when I try to load the model the following error outputs:

Error
[image: screen shot of the error]

Initially, I had the same problem but with `'Functional'` and I searched for similar errors. Swapping the word `Functional` for the word `Model`, this error can be [avoided](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/3786). But a new error (screenshot above) shows.

Maybe I'm misunderstanding something. I think it may have something to do with the conversion. If not, anyone knows how can I fix this new error? Maybe in a similar way as the 'Functional' error?